# Как декодировать разнотипный JSON в Go?

Tags: json, golang

Как в golang работать с json?
Читаю про стандартную библиотеку для json.
Получается мне надо описывать кучу типов для каждого варианта?
Или есть какой-нибудь пакет, чтоб он сам распарсивал, а я указывал, какое именно звено я хочу и получал результат?

С WebSocket приходит строка, например,

```
{ 
    "function": "Get_Me_List1", 
    "data": {
        "param1": 1, 
        "param2": 2
    }
}
```

И в то же время будут и другие значения приходить.
Я хочу сперва определить `function` и потом через `case switch` направить на соответствующую функцию с параметрами в программе go.
Просто, как быть, если будут, например, и другие функции? Что-то типа

```
{
    "function": "Values_Add",
    "data": {
                 param_array:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 param:777
              }
}
```

Сперва мне нужно идентифицировать первое звено,т.е. узнать "function" и "data". Потом я передаю функции Values_Add(data) в go data (т.е параметры [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] и param:777) . Она должна так-же распарсить по своему типу, т.к. она будет принимать param_array и param .И потом уже работать со значениями.

**Спасибо Ainar-G /Nofate♦**
**Решение:**

```
type struct_json struct { 
    Function string
    Data     json.RawMessage  
}

type get_Dir_Db_struct_json struct { 
    Param1 string
    Param2 string 
}

  var var_struct_json = &struct_json{}
  var b = []byte(`{"function": "get_Dir_Db", "data": {"param1":"111","param2":"222"} }`)
  err := json.Unmarshal(b, var_struct_json)
  if err != nil {
    log.Println("error:", err)
  }

  switch var_struct_json.Function {
  case "get_Dir_Db":
    var var_get_Dir_Db_struct_json  = &get_Dir_Db_struct_json{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(var_struct_json.Data, var_get_Dir_Db_struct_json)
    if err != nil {
      log.Println("error:", err)
    }
    log.Println("-",var_get_Dir_Db_struct_json.Param1)
  case "other":
  // ...
  default:
    log.Println("Функция,которую отослал клиент, не распознана- ", var_struct_json.Function)
  }
```

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Опишите, чего вы хотите добиться, что уже есть, и что не работает/не устраивает.

Comment: Обновил. Хочу, что-то типа такого сделать....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если действительно работа с JSON-RPC, то см. ответ Nofate. В общем же случае для этого используется [`json.RawMessage`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage). [Пример](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_RawMessage) из доков:

```
type Color struct {
    Space string          // Тип цвета, по нему распознаём, что делать дальше.
    Point json.RawMessage // Внутренний JSON, который будет парситься 
                          // в зависимости от типа.
}
```

Comment: проверил-сервер получает строку {"function":"get_Dir_Db","data":"5"} . Простой вопрос- Как мне получить data стандартной библиотекой? т.е. 5 ? Я этот Unmarschal уже кручу-кручу во всех вариантах, а оно не выдаёт

Comment: Что конкретно вам не понятно в примере с цветами из стандартной библиотеки? Ответ на ваш вопрос - http://play.golang.org/p/Tp5T44RLEX.

Comment: Спасибо. Та вот я ж её и хотел прицепить, но делал неправильно. Теперь понятно)))

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что вы пытаетесь заново изобрести [JSON-RPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC)

Насколько я могу судить, это есть в Go из коробки: http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/jsonrpc/

Comment: Похоже то что нужно-надо разбираться. А это будет работать с WebSocket протоколом? т.к. отправляет именно браузер.

Comment: проверил-сервер получает строку {"function":"get_Dir_Db","data":"5"} . Простой вопрос- Как мне получить data стандартной библиотекой? т.е. 5 ? Я этот Unmarschal уже кручу-кручу во всех вариантах, а оно не выдаёт